# Validating a Devise User password WITHOUT changing it

Tags: security, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, passwords

i am using Devise and devise_security_extension.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

I tried to figure out how i could validate a provided password WITHOUT updating a User record.
Validation (password was not used before, password is complex enough ....)

For example:

```
john = User.find(1)
john.password              = "Testing"
john.password_confirmation = "Testing"
result = john.save
```

Result would return true or false. With result.errors i would get the related error messages (Thats exactly what i want but without really change this user password).

My Problem is that this would really change the password of this user (object). That would cause problems with old_passwords.

- Is there any way to do a dry run ? (result = john.save_dry_run)

FYI:

I already tried to change the User password and change it back after i got the result. But this is really ugly and also make much trouble with devise old_passwords table.

I hope my question is clear enough. If you need any further information please let me know !

Comment: How about calling `john.valid?` rather than `john.save` in your example?

Comment: I will tried it right now. If its that easy i am happy and angry at the same time. (thanks for your advice)

Comment: Thanks ... thats the answer i am sorry to ask such a question.

Comment: No worries, that's what Stackoverflow is for! I've added the solution as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `valid?` rather than save in your example. This will only run the model validations without actually saving any data to the database:

```
john = User.find(1)
john.password = "Testing"
john.password_confirmation = "Testing"
result = john.valid?
```

You can find more information in [the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).